# Bash redirect output only to a variable

Tags: bash, stdout

I have a function:

```
function getXpath {
    QUERY=$1
    XMLPATH=$2
    XPATH_QUERY=`echo $XPATH_FORMAT | sed -e "s|{query}|"$QUERY"|g" | sed "s|{file}|"$XMLPATH"|g"`
    xpath $XPATH_QUERY
}
```

and I want to call it this way:

> value=`getXpath "$2" "$XMLPATH"`

value is setted well, the problem is that the result is also being written in the console.

How can I do to only set to the var and not write to the console ?

Answer (score 1):

```
xpath $XPATH_QUERY 2>/dev/null
```